# Swift Draw Text at Coordinates on MapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview

What I am trying to do seems like something that should be able to be accomplished I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction. I have a `MKMapView` and what I would like to do is specify some text and be able to place that text at coordinates I specify. I have tried thinking about it and searching and really haven't come to any conclusions about how I might accomplish this. Really the only thing I have come up with to start with is to just use a `UILabel` with my text and place it in the proper place however this really doesn't solve the problem since the label will not move in place with the map as I would like. I also really don't want to use an annotation as I have no need for a pin or image or anything I just want the text to be displayed. So my question is, are there any recommendations for how I might go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Have you considered using `mapView(_:viewFor:)` and having a custom view that is basically just a `UILabel`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview

Comment: You're definitely going to need to make use of `MKMapViewDelegate` if you aren't already: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to follow the raywanderlich tutorial for this titled Honolulu. https://www.raywenderlich.com/548-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started

basically you'll want to drop a custom pin that is actually the uilabel.

The other option is to make the pin transparent and add a annotation that is forced to display without a tap.

The last option I can think of is that the pins that are dropped on the map have a title that displays the name. You can change the title dynamically and make the pin transparent.

Seriously look at the tutorial and scroll down/look at the images to see what I'm talking about.